# jaxb binding annotation element from another schema and library

Tags: web-services, binding, xsd, jaxb

I'm writing a Web service that exchange some signed information as part of the messages (not in the headers) and I would like to know how I should make the binding to avoid that xjc generates classes for XML signature schema and instead of it I could binding it to a class of a security library.

How I could make the binding? What kind of the class of the library should I use?

In a simplified way the mapping I need it for the following structure:

```
  <xsd:element name="VerifyDetachedDocument">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="tns:Document"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ds:Signature"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
```

where ds is the prefix schema from the xml signature schema.

And I would like to bind this element to a class of the library or to org.w3c.dom.Element class. How I could do it?

Could yo be so kind of helping me, please?

Thanks in advance,

Best regards.